# How to SUMIF having multiple column inverval and only one column to sum

Tags: excel, vba

I extract a report from a store that will provide multiple names (that can be repeated across columns and rows) spread in multiple columns and some fruits they have bought.

I need to sum the amount of fruits per individual name. That would be easy using SUMIF if I had every name stacked into one column, but the names appears into multiple column and SUMIF doesn't work for that (as you can see on the image below):

[image]

Since in this example I only have 3 names and bananas for representation, the sum needs to provide 9 bananas for each name (since each name appears at least one time per row), but it's only giving me 3 for each name.

Please considerar that in the actual report we can have 20+ columns of names (employees of a company) and some blank cells between them.

I've also considered using pivot table, but the problem is the same.

How can I achieve this sum?

Edit 1: Important to notice that the fruit column is not a fixed number and values can be sorted, like that:

[image]

In this case, each one would have 23 bananas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$C$10=F2)*$D$2:$D$10)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Nice! Also, if OP wants to do the same for "Orange" and "Apple", he can just un-anchor the `$D$2:$D$10` columns, `D$2:D$10` and drag the formula left, after also anchoring `F2` to the column, `$F2`.

Comment: I didn't know you could apply conditions inside the SUMPRODUCT. Thanks so much, it worked like a charm :D Excel is struggling a little bit since there're a lot of data, but it works.

Comment: @BruceWayne let's say we have all names into one column and values inside a unique cell, like A2 = "Roberto Carlos Maria", is it possible to make a SUMPRODUCT or SUMIF like "If cells within range A2:A10 have the string "Roberto", sum range D2:D10"? I mean, instead of breaking them into different columns, have the formula to check if the string exist within the cells of the range.

Comment: @SoMeGoD yes it is possible but that is a new question as that will require a new formula.  Please start a new post with that question.  But look into ISNUMBER(SEARCH())

Comment: Awesome! I'll start a new thread about this as recommended. Thanks :D

Comment: Be aware that if the same name appears more than once in a row then the value from column D on that row will also be counted more than once